# How do I switch on an Enum in Swift, depending on the input I provide?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have created the below switch statement to return a Double value depending on what string I input in weightType.

I would like to it with an Enum instead, so that it's more flexible. I though it was an easy change but I have tried all kinds of things and I can't make it work.

Can someone please help me? Thx!

```
var weightType: String = "kettlebell"

func returnWeightLimit() -> Double {
    switch weightType {
    case "barbell": return(132.0)
    case "kettlebell": return(70.5)
    case "dumbbell": return(115.0)
    default: return(0.0)
    }
}

let weightLimit = returnWeightLimit()
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Why not post that code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a raw value-backed enum:

```
enum WeightType: String {
    case barbell
    case kettlebell
    case dumbbell

    var weightLimit: Double {
        switch self {
        case .barbell: return 132.0
        case .kettlebell: return 70.5
        case .dumbbell: return 115.0
        default: return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let str = "kettlebell"
if let weightType = WeightType(rawValue: str) {
    print(weightType.weightLimit)
} else {
    print("You provided the wrong rawValue")
}
```